# How to read the value of a specific cell from MS Excel with ADO query?

Tags: vba, delphi, excel, ado

I am trying to extract data from specific cell from MS Excel worksheet.

```
Select [A1] from [Sheet1$]
```

does not work.

- How to read the value of a specific cell from MS Excel with ADO query ?

this is my connection string if it is from any help.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
User ID=Admin;Data Source=c:\clients.xlsx;
Mode=Share Deny None;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;
HDR=yes";
Jet OLEDB:System database="";
Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";
Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;
Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;
Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;
Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Don''t Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;
Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;
Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False';
```

Comment: OLEDB sees your worksheet as a table, so you need the column headings. For some useful help, see [Technet:Using ADO to Query an Excel Spreadsheet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx) and [how to use ADO to read and write data in Excel workbooks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278973) and [Much ADO about Text files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx)

Comment: I have read those before to post in here, anyway none of them are providing a clue ( or at least i were not able to find ) about solving my issue.

Comment: what error messages are you getting please?

Comment: Have you tried the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` method? For querying a few cells from a closed workbook this would be easier to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've said that the data has headers (using `HDR=YES;` in your connection string), so you need to use the column name from that header row. For instance, if you have a sheet such as this:

```
    A    B
1 CODE  DESCRIPTION
2 100   This is an item description
3 200   This is another item
```

Your `SELECT` statement would be

```
SELECT Code, Description FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Code] = 100
```

The query above would return

```
Code  Description
100   This is an item description
```

If you need a specific cell from the resulting column, you can move to it after the query:

```
ADOQuery1.MoveBy(25);         // Move to row 25 of the results
DescriptStr :=  ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Description').Value;
```

Note that using ADO may not be the best way to access a single cell. Automation, for instance, would be much easier:

```
// You'll need to add ComObj to your uses clause for CreateOleObject
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  XLS: Variant;
  Range: Variant;
  Description: String;
begin
  XLS := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
    XLS.WorkBooks.Open('C:\ExcelDocs\MyFile.xls');

    // Retrieve the cell
    Range := XLS.ActiveWorkBook.WorkSheets[1].Range['B2'];

    // Read its content
    Description := Range.Value;
    ShowMessage(Description);  // Displays 'This is an item description'
  finally
    Range := null;             // Release reference

    XLS.Quit;                  // Close Excel application
    XLS := null;               // Release reference
  end;
end;
```

Comment: As an alternative for a small number of cells `executexcel4macro` method would be faster than opening the workbook and/or easoer to implement than ADO.

Comment: Just tested the newly added source from You, and it worked flawless. Thank You very much. I am quitting looking for the pure SQL approach for now, and will stick with this approach. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure ADO is the best way to get the value of specific cell? ADO treats excel spreadsheets like sql tables and your question is similar to 'how to get record #5 from sql server table'.

Better try OLE automation. There you can easily address single cell or a range of cells. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231614) is an example from Microsoft.

Comment: Good idea, you do not need a table for a single cell. I hope it is okay on memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have headers, you select the name of the header, if you do not, the first column is F1, followed by F2 and so on. You can experiment by using `SELECT * ...` and then looking up the field names.

Comment: Post your connection string.

Comment: i have updated the question with the connection string.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using, and are you on a 64-bit Windows machine or 32-bit?

Comment: The ACE OLEDB provider needs to be installed in ether 32 or 64bit mode. Single installation does not include both (from [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/571116/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-while-platform-cannot-be-changed-from-x64-to-x86)

Comment: is the sql query different on different architectures ?

Comment: You have HDR=Yes, there is no row (cell) A1, A1 is the header. In other words, you have an empty recordset.

Comment: I doubt that it's the query causing the problem, it's more likely the OLE DB Provider cannot connect, so you don't have a valid connection to the table ....

Comment: Are you getting any specific error message that you can show us?

Comment: @Philip the connection says HDR=Yes, see my comment above.

Comment: switched to HDR=no, now the results look better, but i still can not extract the content of a specific single cell..

Comment: @Yordan So what *do* you get (your results)?. You have the annoying habit of not giving sufficient information.

Comment: to get a specific cell from the first row, you could just query one column maybe using the SQL `TOP` keyword

Comment: @Jan Doggen I am actually sorry about this, usually I am trying to make as much as possible the questions in the general terms in order to be more valuable, but seems like not all the time I am succeeding at this target.

Comment: about the current results, I haven't found yet the proper SQL to extract the value of A1 ( which is the actually the question ).
* I am looking only about SQL approach.
The strange part is that now the columns became renamed from A, B, C .. to F1, F2, F3..